# Issue reading CSV file with Pandas for Flask App

Tags: python, pandas, flask, web

I'm creating a Flask app using python and am having an issue pulling data out of the file. Whenever I visit my website I get 'Internal Server Error'.

It's a very basic setup, I have the CSV saved in a folder 'static'. However I can't seem to be able to access through flask.

Really appreciate any advice here. Have tried a ton of solutions and can't get anything to work. Thanks!

```
from app import app
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import pandas as pd

@app.route('/hello', methods=\['GET', 'POST'\])
def helloIndex():
df = pd.read_csv('/static/filename.csv')

    # would put basic python script to run the input data against the data in the CSV here


    if request.method == 'POST':
        output2 = '<b> output data here <>'
        return output2
    return '''
    <form method="POST">
            < HTML here for input data would go here >
    </form>
    '''
```

Comment: The first line of code in the function should be indented...

Comment: First line is indented - just a typo when copying it over here for the post

Comment: A 500 error could be caused by almost anything.  Have you looked in the flask server error log to see the actual error message?

Comment: Is the `static` folder in the root directory?

Comment: I have it set up as: root --> app --> static. should I structure differently?

Comment: `pd.read_csv('/static/filename.csv')` That pathname means it is expecting `static` to be in the root directory.  It's a filename on the local disk drive, not a url.

Answer (score -1):

Change from:

```
def helloIndex():
df = pd.read_csv('/static/filename.csv')
```

To

```
def helloIndex():
   df = pd.read_csv('./static/filename.csv')
```